# need to refactor multiple toggle lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#state-list, #major-list').hide();

  $('#state').bind('click', function() {
    $('#state-list').toggle();
  });

  $('#major').bind('click', function() {
    $('#major-list').toggle();
  });

});
```

All links and lists will follow the naming convention of:

link, link-list, like seen below:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>

<div id="link-list">
...
</div>
```

Is there a way listen for all links and toggle their respective lists, instead of creating a bind click for every link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <a href="#" id="link" class="linksToWatch">Link</a>
 <div id="link-list" class="listsToToggle">

 $('.listsToToggle').hide();

 $('.linksToWatch').bind('click', function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#' + id + '-list').toggle();
 });
```

May be, something like this?